# Does c++ delete expect a pointer or an object?

Tags: c++

I am confused on whether the `delete` statement expects a `pointer` or an `object`.

Sometimes I see the following which suggests a pointer is expected for a paramter

```
int* myAge = new int(12);

delete myAge;
```

And other times I see it used like this

```
Person* friends = new Person[3];

// constructing my friends
friends[0] = new Person("Bob", 21);
friends[1] = new Person("Alice", 19);
friends[2] = new Person("Jack", 5);

// destructing my friends 
delete friends[0]; 
delete friends[1]; // (isn't friends[i] an object?)
delete friends[2];
delete[] friends;
```

Comment: The second example is a type error.

Comment: @melpomene what do you mean?

Comment: `new Person("Bob", 21)` is a pointer. `friends[0]` is a `Person` object. You can't assign it a pointer.

Comment: Let me guess: you come from a Java background?  If you just wanted an array of three `Person` objects, you would write:  `Person friends[3];` and no need for a `new` anywhere.  Also, as a rookie, avoid `new` and `delete` - you will get memory leaks and "use-after-free` errors all over the place.  Instead use `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`+`std::make_unique` and `std::shared_ptr`+`std::make_shared`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> whether the delete statement expects a pointer or an object

`delete` expects a pointer.

The second example that you shared has an error. For the second example to work, the statement

```
Person* friends = new Person[3];
```

must have to be changed to:

```
Person** friends = new Person*[3];
```

See this approach [live here](https://www.ideone.com/jRpmxr).

Because after this statement, you're assigning `Person*` to `friends[i]` (as `new Person("Bob", 21);` would yield a pointer to `Person`, not an object), so to make that statement work, `friends[i]` must have to be `Person*` too.

And in the case of `Person* friends = new Person[3];`, `friends` is just an array of objects. The objects are already constructed by the default no argument constructor. And in case you want to change the data members, you'll have to use setters. And after that, you'll delete this array using `delete[] friends;`.

```
Person* friends = new Person[3];

// setting the data members
friends[0].setPerson("Bob", 21);
friends[1].setPerson("Alice", 19);
friends[2].setPerson("Jack", 5);

// destructing my friends
delete[] friends;
```

See this second approach [live here](https://www.ideone.com/mfNbfQ).

Comment: So does that mean `Person* friends = new Person[3];` 3 `Person` objects would have already been generated for me?

Comment: yes, in the case of `Person* friends = new Person[3];`, `friends` is just an array of objects. And you'll delete this array using `delete[] friends;`